# In Monopoly, Can I mortgage properties during an auction time?

Tags: monopoly

In Monopoly, Can I mortgage properties during an auction time? Monopoly on the Nintendo Gameboy, Nintendo Entertainment System, and Super Nintendo like to go by the real rules. All though on the Nintendo, it does not allow you to mortgage properties during an auction site. Does that rule apply, if you are playing the real actual board game? Can you build houses and hotels during an auction time?

Comment: I'm not sure why you say the Nintendo version doesn't allow you to mortgage during an auction. I haven't played the Game Boy one, but both the NES and SNES ones certainly allow it (press Select during the auction).

Answer (score 12):

**Yes.**

For mortgages [the rules](https://www.hasbro.com/common/instruct/00009.pdf) state:

> Unimproved properties can be mortgaged through the Bank at any time.

and for building houses:

> you may buy and erect at any time as many houses as your judgement and financial standing will allow.

Comment: I agree with the above interpretation of the rule.  Although I am not a fan of house rules in Monopoly, there is a procedural snag.  We play that if a player has dropped his/her dice and that dice roll happens before someone announced their intention to improve a property then the move forward of the token piece occurs prior to the improvements.